# Do the ARC compiler automatically determines whether to retain or assign in overridden class depending on property attributes?

Tags: objective-c, setter, automatic-ref-counting

I don't know assembler well enough to understand so complicated code as Assembly for whole project, but I noticed that if I put `strong` attribute to the property, a `_objc_storeStrong` call shows up near the line in my setter where I change my properly;

```
@interface ClassName : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSSet *mySet;

@end


@implementation ClassName

@synthesize mySet;

-(void)setMySet:(NSSet *)newMySet
{
   mySet = newMySet;
   //do stuff
}

@end
```

So? am I right? Do the ARC compiler automatically determines whether to retain or assign in overridden class depending on property attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes. Because you set the property as `strong`, it will be retained by the object. If you declare the property as `weak`, the implied (synthesized) variable is `__weak NSSet *mySet` and that won't retain the object, but it *will* be a auto-zeroing pointer.

Comment: Thanks. So compiler determines it depending on implied iVar? So I set up property, it implies the ivar and then compiler decides how to store value in it? It doesn't better much for me, but may be I'll understand it better.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `strong` implies `__strong`, which is the same as `retain` in MRC. (The default is `assign` or `unsafe_unretained`, both of which imply `__unsafe_unretained`, which is the same as `assign` in MRC).